# Interrupt deprivileging in ARM V6 micro controller

Tags: armv6

I am using an ARM V6 based micro controller.
I have a use case where an interrupt routine needs to be executed in a unprivilege mode (User mode)
This is because :

- the function is considered non trusted
- but needs a real time response

I see CCR does not have bitfield NONBASETHRDENA in ARM V6.

So the question is "Can we de privilege an interrupt in arm v6 ?"
If yes, It will be really exciting to see an example.